# Dpkg can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so'

Tags: apt, raspbian, dpkg

When I tried to `sudo apt upgrade` my Raspberry Pi system running Raspbian Buster, `dpkg` errored out when it got to the configuration of `openssh-server`:

```bsh
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rpi.gpio-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: invalid ELF header at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 93.
  at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/Fcntl.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/Seekable.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/Seekable.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/File.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/File.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.28/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 3.
) -- aborting
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1) ...
Can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: invalid ELF header at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 93.
  at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/Fcntl.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Upon seeing the line in the error that suggested configuration issues, I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, only to get the same output again:

```bsh
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1) ...
Can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: invalid ELF header at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 93.
  at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/Fcntl.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
```

When it comes to Linux package configuration and the vagueries of the `openssh-server` package, I am a complete noob. I haven't been able to find any literature or forum posts online describing a similar issue and a workable solution. How can I go about addressing this apparent library conflict?

**EDIT:**

```bsh
$ sudo apt --reinstall install perl-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rpi.gpio-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,352 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.os6.org/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf perl-base armhf 5.28.1-6 [1,352 kB]
Fetched 1,352 kB in 1s (1,069 kB/s)
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: invalid ELF header at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 93.
  at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/Fcntl.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/Seekable.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/Seekable.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/File.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/IO/File.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.28/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 3.
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 43627 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.28.1-6_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.28.1-6) over (5.28.1-6) ...
Setting up perl-base (5.28.1-6) ...
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1) ...
Can't load '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: invalid ELF header at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 93........................]
  at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/Fcntl.pm line 11........................................................]
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 11............................]
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28/POSIX.pm line 17........................]
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7........................................]
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Illegal instruction
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```bsh
$ ls /usr/bin/ -lah | grep perl
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root    2.8M Mar 31  2019 perl
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root    2.8M Mar 31  2019 perl5.28.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    5.5K Mar 31  2019 perl5.28-arm-linux-gnueabihf
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root     46K Mar 31  2019 perlbug
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     125 Mar 31  2019 perldoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     11K Mar 31  2019 perlivp
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root     46K Mar 31  2019 perlthanks
```

Comment: What is the result of `apt-get --reinstall install perl-base`? Can an `apt update` and `apt --fix-broken install` report any other errors? It appears you are missing perl which is odd.

Comment: Unfortunately, @kemotep, no. See edits above for terminal output. Both the reinstall and fix-broken commands return the same error.

Comment: Looks like perl is missing configurations or is some how broken. The advice I am seeing is to either reinstall perl (which you report to not be working. You could install it manually with `dpkg`) or reinstall the operating system. Are you in a position where starting over is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused by a chicken-and-egg problem between perl and [*debconf*](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf). *Debconf* is an optional feature allowing packages to get configuration questions at the start rather than in the middle of the installation: it's not vital, so that's the one to move away.

On a Debian 9 or 10 system, its invocation is configured from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`:

> ```
> // Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed.
> // If you don't like it, comment it out.
> DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
> ```

So just comment out the `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs` line above.

From the error message, I would think that the package [`libperl5.28`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/armhf/libperl5.28/filelist) might have corrupted contents. Either reinstall it along `perl-base` with *apt*:

```
apt-get --fix-broken --reinstall install perl-base libperl5.28
```

Or (if *apt* also needed Perl and also chokes) try directly with *dpkg* since it was downloaded:

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.28_5.28.1-6_armhf.deb
```

In case you get more errors, that could mean something else happened before on the system but wasn't explained in the question. Knowing what error happened before on the system could then help fix it.

Once perl is back working, you can uncomment the previous line to enable *debconf* back.

Comment: Works perfectly and brilliantly explained too! I had to comment out the `Pre-Install-Pkgs` line and run the `apt` command for both `perl-base` and `libperl5.28` to restore normal operation. Thank you very much for the help!